# Intersection constraints?

Tags: cad, autodesk-inventor

Is it possible to constraint a line on another line by way of a perpendicular constraint? This also includes center points on other objects.

What I am trying to accomplish is to move a rectangular array to a set distance from another object (all in sketch) at the center points. So basically, I need to move this array to a set location from the corner or another object (inside the object which is a rectangle)

I have been trying to get this to work in different ways for the past 3 hours with no luck or even trying to find additional help on the Autocad inventor forums.

Please keep in mind, I am VERY new to Inventor (started with Fusion and, YUP, there are a ton of differences). Are there even guidelines? I will not be able to use the grid as my measurements are not a whole number and precision is 3 places.

Hopefully, I have explained what I am trying to accomplish, If you need any further information to assist me in answering this question, please do not hesitate to ask. :)

Attached is a sample of what I am dealing with. the column of objects HAS to be x, y from the top and right sides of the outer rectangle. The additional lines outside of the rectangle in the upper right are directional lines for creating arrays only.

[image: Sample]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes this is 100% possible. Please can you provide screenshots to clarify your exact situation?

Comment: (I don't have inventor installed any more so can't provide screenshots of my own)

Comment: just now updated

Comment: So the problem is that the black lines are in a different sketch, so you can't directly dimension to them? If so then you need to use a tool called project geometry, which will will make a a copy of the black lines in in yellow, which you can then dimension to.

Comment: You can also create a point in your sketch (to the right of the spine button), and define it's position using constraints to give you something more intuitive to to dimension against. For example by assigning it's to the midpoint of a line, or to be coincident to two different lines giving a virtual intersection

Comment: interesting about the different sketch. All objects are on one sketch (so far)I was kinda surprised about the two different colors (I thought that the object's color would be the same since they are on one sketch.

Comment: Ahhh - the different colour is indicating which lines are fully constrained (black) and which are under constrained (purple). You will be able to drag the purple ones around. In which case you can ignore my first comment and just dimension directly from the point to the black lines :)

Comment: ok, so in regards to actually placing the point... is this something I have to calculate the exact location or will it be possible to place it by distance. Say so many mm from the left and top of the outer sides? And how do you "snap" to that point? by a constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I've re-installed Inventor...

It's only now become apparent to me that your slot is actually a rectangle with all four corners filleted?

If you instead create a 'slot' entity directly, then the relevant point will be automatically created for you, ready for dimensioning.

In any case, below I have shown both how to add the point I was describing before to allow you to dimension to the midpoint, and also I have shown how to make a slot entity instead, which is better practice

[image]

Comment: OMG! You are awesome sir! Thank You.

Comment: No problem! Took a while for you to notice my answer, it seems 

Comment: Sorry dude.... I've been having health issues for more than a year, so ... yeah. :(